# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Supports Facebook messenger ??... How to install facebook messenger app

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, root, lts, facebook

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS yesterday.

While using facebook through browser, it asked whether to install facebook app or not. I said yes and its installed.

But while trying to open the facebook from the icon created on the desktop side bar, it just pops up and displays the initial facebook screen and then hangs. The whole linux hangs and not able to kill any process.. only restart is the possible option.

Also I tried to access the root folder. It says u dont have permission. How to get root permission?. I am the only one user.

Answer (score 2):

I think Ubuntu’s web app integration has changed in 14.04. When you create a web app for a service like Gmail, Facebook, Ubuntu will now use the same browser used on Ubuntu Mobile. This theoretically makes web apps more consistent between the desktop and mobile versions of Ubuntu, but it’s a problem if you actually want to use these apps. This browser doesn’t work anywhere near as well and doesn’t even have access to the Flash plug-in.

If you want launcher icons for your favorite web apps, you should probably skip Ubuntu’s native integration features. Instead, install the Chromium or Chrome web browsers and use the Tools > Create application shortcuts menu option to create launcher icons and separate windows for your preferred web apps.

- If you want to uninstall it--

**Go to the Software Center and search for the specific web app and uninstall it. E.g.
unity-webapps-gmail or unity-webapps-googledocs**

- After uninstall you can add it manually using

  1. Open a terminal window.
  2. Type in the following commands then hit Enter after each.

> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps-dependencies
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:folke-schwinning/personal
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install desktop-facebook
> sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:noobslab/apps-dependencies
> ```

I think this will work better...

Thanks